# ¿Cómo puedo obtener un número aleatorio en un rango?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, postgresql

¿Cómo puedo hacer para obtener un número aleatorio entre dos valores?
Entre un `mínimo` y un `máximo`, por ejemplo, un número entre `1` y `10`

Intente haciendo un `SELECT` y usando `RAND()`:

```
SELECT RAND() as aleatorio
```

Pero no se como indicar el rango, porque lo siguiente no funciona:

```
SELECT RAND(1, 10) as aleatorio
```

Obtengo el siguiente error:

> #1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'RAND'

Comment: ¿Que sentido tiene etiquetar con 4 motores de base de datos?

Comment: @alvalongo lo que busca es dar una respuesta general para esos 4 gestores, ya que las soluciones son semejantes, aunque no se si también deberían aplicar otros como MariaDB o SQLite.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Si tomamos en cuenta los valores máximos y mínimos que devuelve la función [`RAND()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand):

> Devuelve un valor aleatorio de coma flotante v en el rango `0 <= v < 1.0`.

Una solución es usar la siguiente fórmula:

```
(RAND() * (max - min)) + min
```

---

#### Opción resultado decimal:

Si se busca obtener un número con decimales, entonces podemos hacer:

```
SELECT ((RAND() * (10 - 1)) + 1) AS aleatorio
```

Esto devolverá un número **mayor igual a 1 y menor a 10**

---

#### Opción resultado entero:

Si se busca obtener un número entero, entonces podemos utilizar:

- [`FLOOR()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_floor): obtenedremos un número entero **mayor igual a 1 y menor a 10**.
- [`CEIL()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_ceil): obtenedremos un número entero **mayor a 1 y menor igual a 10**.
- [`ROUND()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round): obtenedremos un número entero **mayor igual a 1 y menor igual a 10**.

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT ROUND((RAND() * (10 - 1)) + 1) AS aleatorio
```

---

#### Observaciones:

- En `PostgreSQL` no existe `rand()`, sino [`random()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/functions-math.html) y el funcionamiento es idéntico.
- En `SQLServer`:

  - Es necesario indicar la cantidad de decimales para `ROUND`, es decir `ROUND(x, y)`, donde `y` es la cantidad de decimales.
  - No existe `CEIL()`, sino [`CEILING`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ceiling-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), y funciona igual.

Comment: Excelente contenido @Marcos, sobre todo por que se queda como *Wiki* de comunidad

Answer (score 2):

La función `RAND()` no es una buena opción para generar números aleatorios ya que siempre devolverá el mismo número dentro de la consulta. Lo cual podemos comprobar al ejecutar el siguiente código:

```
SELECT RAND() 
FROM sys.all_columns;
```

Una mejor opción es utilizar `NEWID()` para generar valores aleatorios. Para obtener enteros, simplemente agregamos `CHECKSUM()`. Para que siempre sean positivos, agregamos `ABS()`. Para generar un rango, utilizamos el módulo con la amplitud del rango y le sumamos el valor inicial. De tal modo, así quedaría la fórmula:

```
DECLARE @LimiteInferior int = 1,
        @LimiteSuperior int = 10;

DECLARE @Rango          int = @LimiteSuperior - @LimiteInferior + 1;

SELECT ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % @Rango + @LimiteInferior
FROM sys.all_columns; --Usado para generar varias filas
```

**Aclaración**: Esta solución es para SQL Server. No se ha probado con otros RDBMS. Se presenta porque la pregunta incluye 4 RDBMS distintos.

Answer (score 2):

Esta solución es para **Oracle**.

```
select dbms_random.value(1,10) as azar 
from dual;
```

Ref: [108 DBMS_RANDOM](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_random.htm#ARPLS67507)

Answer (score 0):

Este es el que me funciono : SELECT FLOOR( i + RAND() * ( f - i + 1 ) );

Ejemplo: obtendremos un valor aleatorio entre [5,10] donde:

i=5

f=10

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]